# How can I copy and backup my cronjobs?

Tags: cron

Im new in Ubuntu .. and I am wondering how can i access the /var/spool/cron/crontab directory .. I just want to copy my cronjob to /etc/cron.daily .

Comment: It's hard to know what you are trying to do - what's your intended result?

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you want to achieve and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Answer (score 5):

Whatever system backup you do should include your /var/spool and /etc directories anyway, so there is nothing special you need to do in order to backup your cron tables.

The per-user cron tables are in `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/`.  You do not edit these files directly, instead you use `crontab -e` to edit them (or `crontab -l` to view them).

The system-wide cron table is split into multiple files that reside in `/etc/cron.d/`

The additional directories such as `/etc/cron.daily/`, `/etc/cron.hourly/` and so on do not hold cron tables but instead hold scripts that are called at that frequency by your system cron tables.  They are designed to allow packages to drop in tasks to these directories if they need a task run regularly.

If you want to change the user that a cron runs under, the safest way to do it is to `crontab -e` as the first user, delete the line from their cron table, log in as the second user, `crontab -e`, and then add the line to that user's cron table.

If you want to place an entry in the system cron table, you could write up a cron table and place it in `/etc/cron.d/`.  Though unless you are installing your own software system-wide, it usually makes sense to stick with the per-user cron tables.

Comment: In some OS like Debian/CentOS cron folder is /var/spool/cron/. But at any case you can backup your cron jobs regardless of the folder location wiht: crontab -l > my_crontab.backup

Comment: If you do that, remember also that you may have added some scripts to /etc/cron.d or to the /etc/cron.* directories.  And that other users may have cron tasks on their accounts if there are other users.

Comment: corrcet, but normally you should not have custom scripts in /etc/cron.d but store them in the user folder. Also when saying "your jobs" it's meant current user or root.

Answer (score 1):

Although the `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/` is not accessible without superuser privileges, you can still access your own crontab using `crontab -l`:

```
$ whoami
steeldriver
$ cat /var/spool/cron/crontabs/steeldriver
cat: /var/spool/cron/crontabs/steeldriver: Permission denied
```

but

```
$ crontab -l | tail -1
* * * * * /usr/bin/printenv > $HOME/cronenv
```

This is achieved through the magic of [sticky bits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_bit):

```
$ ls -ld /var/spool/cron/crontabs/
drwx-wx--T 2 root crontab 4096 Jun  7 19:34 /var/spool/cron/crontabs/
```

Comment: And `crontab(1)` being setgid, IIRC.